# Most efficient way to store a section of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making an application, and I need to store "snapshots" of the canvas so I can use them later.

I'm currently turning the canvas into a dataUrl, creating a 'new Image()' with it, and storing it into an array. But this turns out to be quite slow, and kind of freezes the application for a split second when it happens.

There's one problem I'm aware of; it saves the entire canvas, while I only need to save a small section of it.

So, is there any faster way to save the current canvas, or is there any way to turn only a small section into a dataUrl without creating new canvases every time?

Comment: What are the sizes of 1) the canvas and 2) the small sections ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist They both vary. The canvas is mostly about 1000x1000, sections are usually from 50x50 to 500x500 I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a canvas the size of the area you want to save:

```
var save_area = document.createElement("canvas");
save_area.width = x1 - x0;
save_area.height = y1 - y0;
```

Then you draw the original canvas into the save area, translated by `(-x0, -y0)` so that the part you're interested in is copied in `save_area` pixels.

```
save_area.getContext("2d").drawImage(original_canvas, -x0, -y0);
```

To restore just draw back the `save_area` into the canvas after first clearing the affected portion (this is needed to handle transparency correctly).

```
original_canvas_context.clearRect(x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0);
original_canvas_context.drawImage(save_area, x0, y0);
```

You can see a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmrswch/2/

Comment: Hmm, that requires me to juggle around 10-50 save-canvases. I'll give it a try though and see if it works better, thanks.

Comment: You need a place where to store the saved parts. Using a separate canvas for each part is IMO the best approach. If you're implementing UNDO/REDO the command pattern is better, but that's another story...

Comment: Ended up making a temporary canvas, and just resizing it and drawing the save section into it, and then using the 'new Image()' array thing I was already using. Works perfect now.